# How to make a 2D plot with PGFPLOT – two functions intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've to make a plot of these two functions:

c_1(c_2): 2 + 1/2c_2
c_2(c_1): 2 + 1/2c_1

It doesn't really matters if c_2 is in the axe y or x (same applies for c_1).

I plotted the functions in desmos but I think it would be nicer to make the graph with pgfplots instead of just importing the image

[image]

I've the basic example of 2d plotting but I can't seem to figure it out how to plot two functions with different variables.

I tried to play with this example but I just got errors and errors.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $c_1$,
ylabel = {$c_2$},
]

%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
domain=0:10,
samples=100,
color=red,
]
{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 - 2x - 1$}

%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
domain=0:10,
samples=100,
color=blue,
]
{x^2 + 2*x + 1};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 + 2x + 1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Sorry if it's a simple question. I'm an undergrad student from humanities. I don't have a strong basis of math or LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! I do not quite understand why you plot parabolae if you seem to want lines. Anyway, otherwise you are rather close. I changed a couple of things and added a few more elements such as the grid.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}%<- use a smaller version if you have an older installation
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
minor tick num=4,
grid=both,
xlabel = $c_1$,
ylabel = {$c_2$},
xmin=0,
xmax=4,
ymin=0,
enlargelimits=0.1,
legend style={at={(0.1,0.15)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [
domain=0:10,
samples=100,
color=blue,
]
{2+x/2};
\addlegendentry{$c_2=\frac{c_1}{2}-1$}

\addplot [
domain=0:10,
samples=100,
color=red,
]
{2*x-4};
\addlegendentry{$c_2=2c_1-4$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! The graph is great. Yeah, you are right. I was trying to plot two lines. 

I know I can change the legends, but I'd like to know why did you write those legends instead of c_1(c_2): 2 + 1/2c_2 and c_2(c_1): 2 + 1/2c_1

Comment: @user10926715 You can change them but these are the expressions for the lines given that you name the coordinates `c_1` and `c_2`.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Got it. I changed the axis to left only, because I want to plot just the positive side and now the blue line isn't starting in the Y axis. Do you know why this might happen? https://imgur.com/nGz2YMD

Comment: @user10926715 Yes, this is because I added `enlargelimits=0.1,`.